# Computing things in Effective field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, effective-field-theory

I find it hard to go through most of the homework problems in an effective field theory course. In fact I think I have developed a general disdain in solving hard Quantum field theory related problems. Is there a text that essentially focuses on how to solve such problems. A text Q and A for Effective field theory?

ADDENDUM~
10/13/2014

Ok, I just figured out that the next homework sets assume solid knowledge of Standard Model Physics(Solid enough to make strange calculations). Is there a text I can look over in about a night or at most 2, to attain this level? A text focusing on how to compute things with an eye towards effective field theory?

Comment: Simply putting equations into a CAS doesn't give you a decent result. Further, many problems aren't quite solvable in their full form, so a CAS would be useless.

Comment: Yeah CAS is fairly unreliable sometimes.  I am looking at the problem sets of the EFT mitX course. Some of the homework is ridiculous. I have never really cared much about computing things, but I am sort of looking for a text with may be a summary of the calculus tricks and techniques for QFT without much of the physics , just how to easily solve problems. Is such a text even available?

Comment: I think I am asking for a text on purely how to compute quantities in QFT ~ EFT . I know this is not really the place, but I am looking for a problem and solution type of treatment.

Comment: [This book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Problem-Book-Quantum-Field-Theory/dp/3540770135) is quite good for QFT (canonical formalism, no path integrals sadly), but focusses on the more 'usual' problems of QFT and not EFT.... Might be worth looking into though.

Comment: I just downloaded it. I also found a text with rather peculiar words that remind me of someone I know especially to words in the prologue. Any thoughts on the nature of the material presented? http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~hgeorgi/review.pdf

Comment: Ok, I just figured out that the next homework sets assume solid knowledge of Standard Model Physics(Solid enough to make strange calculations). Is there a text I can look over in about a night or at most 2, to attain this level? A text focusing on how to compute things with an eye towards effective field theory?

Comment: Just discovered Ian's notes on qft III are actually for standard model. Nice.